# Filling an array from a dynamic list of drawables using getIdentifier fails

Tags: android, arrays, drawable

As the title says, my code fails when I try to fill the array, but it works with just one item

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int width=getWidth(this);
    int height=getHeight(this);
    String resolution= new String();
    tamanhos= new String[]{ "240x320","320x480","480x800","800x1280"};
    wallpapers= new String[]{ "fdonegrobrillo"};
    resolution=tamanhos[3]

    mImages=new int[wallpapers.length];
    Resources res= this.getResources();
    for(int i=0;i<wallpapers.length;i++){
    mImages[i]=res.getIdentifier(wallpapers[i]+resolution, "drawable",this.getPackageName());
}
```

I have all the corresponding drawables. When i try with just one item the app works, but if I add another item to wallpapers array, it throws an error (fatal signal 11(SIGSEGV))

I tried with a harcoded array like this

```
mImages=new int[]{
        this.getResources().getIdentifier("fdobyn800x1280",
                  "drawable", this.getPackageName())

};
```

I works, but its the same when i add another item

```
mImages=new int[]{
        this.getResources().getIdentifier("fdobyn800x1280",
                  "drawable", this.getPackageName()),
        this.getResources().getIdentifier("fdonegrobrillo800x1280",
                          "drawable", this.getPackageName())

};
```

Answer (score 0):

May be problem at not in wallpapers array. It code works fine and not throws any errors.

```
package com.example;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MyActivity extends Activity {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            //int width=getWidth(this);
            //int height=getHeight(this);
            String resolution= new String();
            String[] tamanhos= new String[]{"240x320","320x480","480x800","800x1280"};
            String[] wallpapers= new String[]{"fdonegrobrillo", "2", "3"};
            resolution=tamanhos[3];

            int[] mImages=new int[wallpapers.length];
            Resources res= this.getResources();
            for(int i=0;i<wallpapers.length;i++){
                mImages[i]=res.getIdentifier(wallpapers[i]+resolution, "drawable",this.getPackageName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem occurs when i call res.getIdentifier two times with diferent parameters